# LISP function that returns complete binary tree

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to do a lisp function that will receive a list and will return a complete binary tree whose nodes are populated from the elements of the list in the same order. 
For example,

```
(makeTree '(4 3 9 10))
(4 (3 (9 () ()) ()) (10 () ()))
```

[image]

To do it, I am using a function that splits the list in 2. So, what I did is tried to separate the head of the list from it's tail and then use the split function to be able to do the binary tree. But I am having trouble implementing it. Can someone help me please?
Here is my code so far:

```
(defun aux-head (l n)
   (if (= n 0) '()
       (cons (car l) (aux-head (cdr l)(- n 1)))))
(defun aux-tail (l n)
   (if (= n 0) l
       (aux-tail (cdr l) (- n 1))))
(defun split (lst)
   (cond
       ((null lst) '(()()))
       ((evenp (length lst))
          (list (aux-head lst (/ (length lst) 2))(aux-tail lst (/ (length lst) 2))))
       ((oddp (length lst))
          (list (aux-head lst (+ (floor (length lst) 2) 1))
                (aux-tail lst (+ (floor (length lst) 2) 1))))))
(defun make-cbtree (lst)
   (cond
       ((null lst) '(()()))
       ((car lst)
          ((split ((cdr lst)))))))
```

Comment: what is the problem with the code?

Comment: There is no error in the code so far, it’s just that I need help understanding how I have to do my code to be able to get the result I need, which is a complete binary tree  of a list

Comment: I know what I have to do, it’s just that I don’t know how to do it

Comment: how can you say by the input that the result is `(4 (3 (9 () ()) ()) (10 () ()))`, not  `(4 (3 (9 () ()) (10 () ())) ())` ? is there any special ruleset? because otherwise the task is ambiguous

Comment: It's not me that says it. It's what we are asked to do. I added a picture of the binary tree, maybe it can help

Comment: @Jennifer, oh, it's a binary *search* tree ) i see

Comment: @leetwinski yes, sorry, I didn’t make myself clear at the beginning

Comment: @Jennifer, in this case `(4 (3 (9 () ()) ()) (10 () ()))` seems to be malformed BST, since `9` node is left of `3`, which leads to this tree being traversed as `(9 3 4 10)` . it should rather be `(4 (3 () ()) (9 () (10 () ())))`, if you process `(4 3 9 10)` left to right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the common approach to creating a binary search tree is to add items one by one. It could look like this:

```
(defun add-node (tree val)
  (if (null tree)
      (list val () ())
      (destructuring-bind (v l r) tree
        (if (< val v)
            (list v (add-node l val) r)
            (list v l (add-node r val))))))
```

this one inserts the value into the proper position (rebuilding the tree, immutable style):

```
CL-USER> (add-node (list 1 nil nil) 2)
;; (1 NIL (2 NIL NIL))
CL-USER> (add-node (list 1 nil nil) 0)
;; (1 (0 NIL NIL) NIL)
```

what you need next, is to process input list one by one, adding it to the tree, starting from the empty one:

```
(defun make-tree (data)
  (reduce #'add-node data :initial-value nil))

CL-USER> (make-tree (list 4 3 9 10))
;; (4 (3 NIL NIL) (9 NIL (10 NIL NIL)))
```

you can also make up the `traverse` procedure:

```
(defun traverse (tree)
  (when tree
    (append (traverse (cadr tree))
            (list (car tree))
            (traverse (caddr tree)))))

CL-USER> (traverse (make-tree (list 4 3 9 10)))
;; (3 4 9 10)
```

Comment: If I use the split method that I created instead of destructuring-bind, would I get the same result?